# Adding custom attribute to product in Magento 2.3.3 programmatically

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

I want to add a custom attribute to product in Magento 2.3.3 programmatically.

This is my UpgradeData.php

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

When I execute `php magento setup:upgrade`, nothing happens. I tried InstallData.php but it didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1: Create file UpgradeData.php**

We will start with the InstallData class which located in `app/code/Mageplaza/Setup/UpgradeData.php.` The content for this file:

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

}
```

**Step 2: Define the upgrade() method**

```
<?php

public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

}
```

**Step 3: Create custom attribute**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

All done, please run the upgrade script `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to install the module and the product attribute `sample_attribute` will be created. After run upgrade complete, please run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and go to product from admin to check the result. it will show like this:

[image]

**NOTE**:- **Please clear Cache too before checking.**

Comment: Can you show me the console output of setup:upgrade

Comment: Can you please follow my above instructions..? @Birat

Comment: I did still nothing is happening.

Comment: Can you please paste your console output what is the error is showing also i have posted a one more command please run that also, also clear your cache( just rename a cache folder which is located in var/log and then hit the url and check)

Comment: There is no error. The final line of console says "Nothig to import".

Comment: Okay it mean command doesn’t find a file so could you please just let me know in which location you run your command.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207114/discussion-between-arpit-jain-and-birat-bade-shrestha).

Comment: I ran the command from the bin folder and the php file is in app/code/Mazeplaza/HelloWorld/Setup/